# using sscanf to read a string and an int separated by whitespace from textfile

Tags: c, input, linked-list, scanf, stdin

I am getting the full string by using the `%[]`

I believe that is wrong in this case. And the second condition which is to go from the name in the file to the number in the file it does not print that, it just prints a 0. And in the counter I set up, it is saying it only scanned through the line of text once when it should go twice, and for the final code I need it to scan 3 times.

Here is a sample of the input.txt

```
Ant,Adam   10 5
Mander,Sally 4 3
```

And here is a sample of the code

```
FILE *pFilePerson;
char szInputBuffer[100];
int iScanfCnt;
Simulation newSim = newSimulation();
NodeLL linkList;
LinkedList list = newLinkedList();
Event event;
Person person;

pFilePerson = stdin;
while(fgets(szInputBuffer, sizeof szInputBuffer, pFilePerson) != NULL)
{
        iScanfCnt = sscanf(szInputBuffer,"%[] %d",
                    person.szName,
                    person.iDepartTmUnits);                 

    printf("%-7s\n", person.szName);
    printf("%d\n", person.iDepartTmUnits);

                // Check for bad input.  scanf returns the number of valid conversions
        if (iScanfCnt < 2)
        {
            printf("\tWarning: Expected Name and Depart Units, received %d successful values\n"
                , iScanfCnt);
            continue;
        }
}
```

Here is the output I am getting

```
Ant,Adam   10 5

4199680
    Warning: Expected Name and Depart Units, received 1 successful values
Mander,Sally 4 3

4194314
    Warning: Expected Name and Depart Units, received 1 successful values
King,May  6 6
```

Comment: Please let your editor or IDE format your code automatically. Right now it is a mess.

Comment: the posted code is missing the definition of: `Simulation, newSim,
NodeLL, 
LinkedList,  
Event, and 
Person.  The posted code is missing the functions: `newSimulation() and newLinkedList()  So how do you expect us to help you?  We do not have a crystal ball to tell us the many things you didn't

Comment: the posted output is showing 3 lines from ?  certainly not from a input file that your question says only has 2 lines

Comment: @user3629249

the main question i am trying to get out of this is how to go through the file that has white spaces.

It prints out the full line from the text file.

the 41999680 is me printing my attempt to print person.iDepartTmUnits

whatever i'm doing in sscanf is wrong right? i'm trying to ask why thats wrong

Comment: regarding; `%[]`  Between the '['' and the ']' needs to be the termination condition, for instance: '%[^\n]'

Comment: @user3629249 okay, see, I get that much. Now, what I'm having trouble with is the how to copy what is past the name, i.e. the numbers.

Comment: suggest using `fgets()` to read the whole line into a buffer.  then use `strtok()` in a loop to extract a field(s).  then for each field, use  `strdup()` to extract the name`  or use `strtol()` for each of the numeric fields

Comment: regarding the code block beginning with: `if (iScanfCnt < 2)`  Being less than 2 (I.E.  -1 or 0 or 1)  does not result in the assumption stated by the `printf()` statement in the code block.  Suggest reading the MAN page for `scanf()` again

Comment: @user3629249

I got it to work!

    iScanfCnt = sscanf(szInputBuffer, "%15s %d %d",
                event.person.szName,    //Name
                &event.person.iDepartTmUnits,   //Delta Depart
                &event.iTime);  //Delta Arival

Comment: @user3629249 now, I need help with something like this

inserts EVT_ARRIVE and EVT_DEPART events into the simulation's eventList.

how would i go about doing that?

Comment: for your new question, please ask a new question (don't move the goal posts in this question.)